# OpenCV: How to get camera preview sizes natively for Android & desktop

Tags: android, opencv, camera, native, desktop

I would like to know how to get the supported camera preview sizes on Android and desktop, possibly uniformly. I'm on a completely native framework (Qt) and would like to do this fully natively if possible. Currently, I'm using `cv::VideoCapture` to get image data on both platforms but the size is basically guessed.

Answer (score 0):

In Android, the following can be done to get the list of supported preview resolutions:

```
cv::VideoCapture camera(0);
camera.open(0);
union {const char* str; double res;} previewSizes;
previewSizes.res = camera.get(CV_CAP_PROP_SUPPORTED_PREVIEW_SIZES_STRING);
printf("%s",previewSizes.str);
```

This will yield a string as follows:

```
960x720,1280x720,1184x666,960x640,704x576,640x480,352x288,320x240
```

The string needs parsing - not that difficult. This information is extracted by following the source code and it is not documented; any platform-specific camera capture code is in fact not documented. I will try to add the proper documentation to at least the Android side with a PR in the future.